# Spark mapWithState API explanation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have been using the `mapWithState` API in Spark Streaming, but 2 things are not clear about the `StateSpec.function`:

Let's say my function is:

```
def trackStateForKey(batchTime: Time,
                     key: Long,
                     newValue: Option[JobData],
                     currentState: State[JobData]): Option[(Long, JobData)]
```

1. Why is the new value an `Option[T]` type? As far as I've seen, it was always defined for me, and since the method is supposed to be called with a new state, I don't really see the point why it could be optional.
2. What does the return value mean? I tried to find some pointers in the documentations and source code, but none of them describe what it is used for. Since I'm modifying the state of a key using `state.remove()` and `state.update()`, why would I have to do the same with return values?

   In my current implementation I return `None` if I remove the key, and `Some(newState)` if I update it, but I'm not sure if that is correct.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Why is the new value an `Option[T]` type? As far as I've seen, it was
>   always defined for me, and since the method is supposed to be called
>   with a new state, I don't really see the point why it could be
>   optional.

It is an `Option[T]` for the reason that if you set a timeout using `StateSpec.timeout`, e.g:

```
StateSpec.function(spec _).timeout(Milliseconds(5000))
```

then the value passed in once the function times out will be `None` and the `isTimingOut` method on `State[T]` will yield true. This makes sense, because a timeout of the state doesn't mean that a new value has arrived for the specified key, and generally safer to use than passing `null` for `T` (which wouldn't work for primitives anyway) as you expect the user to safely operate on an `Option[T]`.

You can see that in the Sparks implementation:

```
// Get the timed out state records, call the mapping function on each and collect the
// data returned
if (removeTimedoutData && timeoutThresholdTime.isDefined) {
  newStateMap.getByTime(timeoutThresholdTime.get).foreach { case (key, state, _) =>
    wrappedState.wrapTimingOutState(state)
    val returned = mappingFunction(batchTime, key, None, wrappedState) // <-- This.
    mappedData ++= returned
    newStateMap.remove(key)
  }
}
```

> What does the return value mean? I tried to find some pointers in the
>   documentations and source code, but none of them describe what it is
>   used for. Since I'm modifying the state of a key using state.remove()
>   and state.update(), why would I have to do the same with return
>   values?

The return value is a way to pass intermediate state along the spark graph. For example, assume that I want to update my state but also perform some operation in my pipeline with the *intermediate* data, e.g:

```
dStream
  .mapWithState(stateSpec)
  .map(optionIntermediateResult.map(_ * 2))
  .foreachRDD( /* other stuff */)
```

That return value is exactly what allows me to continue operating on said data. If you don't care for the intermediate result and only want the complete state, then outputting `None` is perfectly fine.

#### Edit:

I've written a [blog post](https://blog.yuvalitzchakov.com/exploring-stateful-streaming-with-apache-spark/) (following this question) which attempts to give an in-depth explanation to the API.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.

Comment: The link to the blog post is dead